# Pass value through modal with a href

Tags: html, ejs

I have this code which displays applications using forreach in ejs

```html
          <% applicants.forEach(function(applicant){ %>

          <div class="application">
            <div class="user-info">
              <div class="user-avatar">
                <img src="/images/avatar2.jpg" alt="applicant avatar" />
              </div>
              <h4 class="applicant-name"><%= applicant.username%></h4>
              <p class="application-time">Applied <%= getTimePassed(applicant.dateposted)%></p>
              <div style="margin-left:auto;display:flex;gap:8px;">
                <a href="#accept-modal"><div class="button accept">Accept</div></a>
                                <div class="button reject">Reject</div>
                <a href="#">
                  <div class="mini-button"><img src="/images/rep.svg" alt="report" /></div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="application-text">
<%=applicant.application%>
</p>
<style>
  .application-text { 
word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
            <div class="socials">
              <a href="/profile/<%=applicant.username%>" target="_blank">
                <div class="social-icon">
                  <img src="/images/website.svg" alt="website">
                  <p>View Profile/Portfolio</p>
                </div>
              </a>
              <!---    <a href="#">
                <div class="social-icon">
                  <img src="/images/discord.svg" alt="discord">
                  <p>Discord</p>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <div class="social-icon">
                  <img src="/images/github.svg" alt="github">
                  <p>Github</p>
                </div>
              </a>
            -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <% }); %>
```

When the user presses the accept button, it opens up a modal.

```html
                <a href="#accept-modal"><div class="button accept">Accept</div></a>
```

However, I want to pass through the variable applicant.username to the modal

Here is the modal code

```
<div id="accept-modal" class="modal-window">
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="Close" class="modal-close">Close</a>
    <center><h1>Accept This Application</h1></center>
    <div class="formbold-main-wrapper">
      <!-- Author: FormBold Team -->
      <!-- Learn More: https://formbold.com -->
      <div class="formbold-form-wrapper">
        <form action="/projectaction/<%=data.UniqueID%>/acceptapplication?application=" method="POST">
          <p><strong>Username:</strong> <%= req.query.applicant ? JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(req.query.applicant)).username : '' %></p>
          <button class="formbold-btn">Accept Application</button>
          <p><small>Accepting an application can't be undone</a></small></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I pass through the username variable to the modal, so I can put something like

Username:

Comment: can you create runnable snippet for this ?